# Как получить данные из FacebookSDK для iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook-api, facebooksdk

Мне нужно получить данные пользователя из Facebook. Я успешно получаю такие данные, как имя пользователя, id, фотографию, но при попытке запросить, например, семейное положение, я получаю в ответ пустой словарь.

Я пробовал делать разные запросы, но везде получаю такой результат. Как я могу это исправить? Мой пример кода:

```
   static func getUserRelationship() {
        if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {
            guard let currentUser = getCurrentFacebookUser() else { return }
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/\(currentUser.id)/family", parameters: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET").startWithCompletionHandler({ (requestConnection, result, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    let dictionary = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                    let array = dictionary["data"]
                    print("facebook", result, dictionary, array?.count)
                } else {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
        } else {
            getDataLogin({
                getUserBirthday()
                }, fails: { (error) in

            })
        }
    }
```

Вывожу в консоль результат

```
facebook {
    data =     (
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я неправильно делал запрос. Вот правильно работающий запрос

```
 let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Web
fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile","email"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    } else if result.isCancelled {
        print("Cancelled")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    } else {

    }
}
```

И чтобы получить информацию вызываем следующий код

```
  FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, relationship_status"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbDetails = result as! NSDictionary
            print(fbDetails)
        }
    })
```